# Multiple arguments in NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make an `NSURL` with "multiple parts". I have multiple files that have a name and a number in the filename like: `john2.mp3`, `adam13.mp3`. I randomize a number and a name. Then I want to load the file:

```
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%s%d.mp3",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]], name, number];
```

This doesn't work. It says: `Too many arguments in one method`. What am I doing wrong?

I use Xcode 4.6 and developing for iOS 6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one of your closing square brackets in the wrong place. It should be:

```
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%s%d.mp3",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], name, number]];
```

Also, if `name` is an `NSString` then you need to use `%@`. If `name` is really a `char *` then using `%s` is correct.

It would be clearer to do this instead:

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", name, number];
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:filename withExtension:@"mp3"];
```

Don't try to cram so many nested calls into one line. Break it up. It is easier to read and debug.